# How can Raycast interact with Unity's Canvas UI elements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, unity-ui

I created a Raycast that shoots from an object(not main camera) and I want it to hit UI elements. Example below.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMvrR.png)

UI outlined in orange, big grey plane is a test object, red head is placed upon user's head and green is DrawRay of my raycast attached to an eye. I am trying to make it so user looks at a UI button and raycast can hit that button.

I've been playing around with Graphic raycast but nothing seems to work. Grey plane is still being hit by the raycast. I tried playing with OnPointerEnter but the thing is that my eye raycast is not a mouse/finger touch and is a second pointer. 
Any ideas how to make it work with either isPointerOverGameObject or Graphic Raycaster or any other method?? Or how to create a second pointer that will be the eye raycast?
Current code below.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    GraphicRaycaster gr = this.GetComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();

    PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);

    pointerData.position = Input.mousePosition;

    List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    gr.Raycast(pointerData, results);
    //EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerData, results);
    if (results.Count > 0)
    {
        if (results[0].gameObject.tag == "Test tag")
        {
            Debug.Log("test");
        }
    }




    //----- Failed Graphic raycast experiments above; working RaycastHit below --------


    RaycastHit hit;


        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * -10000f, Color.green);

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward * -1, out hit))
        {

            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        }



}
```

Comment: I'll play around with this tomorrow, but a few things to try: 1) use `Update` instead of `FixedUpdate` 2) wrap it in a `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))` check. Both of these are in the [documentation example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html) and I'm not sure how important it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually much more complicated if you want to do proper interaction with the canvas elements.

I suggest you do not try to roll out the solution yourself, but look at some already made solutions. Most VR toolkits have their own implementations, you could look into [VRTK](https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK)'s example scene 007 - Interactions. You don't have to use VR to use it - just use the fallback SDK.

For more details on how this works, I might point you to the article from Oculus: [Unity Sample Framework](https://developer.oculus.com/blog/unitys-ui-system-in-vr/) (a bit out of date).